# Running two applications on same port and different IP?

Tags: debian, ip, port

Is possible to run two different applications on one port but each on different IP?

Like so:

```
123.456.789.000 -> First NodeJS on port 3000
123.456.789.001 -> Second NodeJS on port 3000
```

Same Debian9 Machine

Answer (score 2):

When socket server is up, the port is reserved for the purpose of this server. It's bound to the host environment and it identifies endpoint within the host, so on single machine you can have only one service listening on specific port to preserve uniqueness.

IP address on the other hand is bound to the network interface and provides the identification of the device within the network. So IP address allows the packages to find you host, whilst port number allows the packages to find your app on your host.

**TLDR: No, it's not possible**

Comment: And what about running Apps on port 3000 and 3001. When I request second server from IP2:3000 there will be proxy to 3001?

Comment: Yes, you can run 1st app on 3000 and 2nd app on 3001. With port forwarding you may be able to achieve simulated 2 apps on one port.